# undo git add to remove staged files

Tags: github

I accidentally  use `git add .` to add files to staging area and did a `git push` which got rejected because I have a large  file. I want to undo `git add .` to unstage the files added. After some search I found `git reset` to reset the staged files. I also go to my work directory and delete that large file.  This time I tried `git add ./myfolder/myfile.py` but still got rejected by remote saying that contains large files. `remote: error: File myfolder/myfile.parquet is 374.75 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`. This file was `git add` in the first time. It seems that `git reset` does not work. How to do this properly?

Comment: What does git status tell you?

Comment: Did you commit before attempting to push?

Comment: I did commit before attempting to push.

Comment: after ```git reset```, ```git status```  result like this ```On branch mychangebranch
nothing to commit, working tree clean```

Comment: That is becuase you commited. So you are not trying to remove staged files. It goes stage -> commit -> push. So you need to undo a commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: I should undo commit. Thanks for  @GoodDeeds 
 Found this link 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git